# Understanding the constraint in Spark's StringIndexer: why must inputCols and outputCols be different?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm in the process of developing a data preprocessing pipeline utilizing Apache Spark, and I've encountered an intriguing behavior with the StringIndexer transformer. In my pipeline, I rely on the StringIndexer to convert categorical columns into numerical representations. However, when I attempt to define the inputCols and outputCols parameters for the StringIndexer, I've observed that Spark imposes a restriction disallowing identical values in both inputCols and outputCols. This is in contrast to other transformers like Imputer, which permit such a configuration.

I'm curious to understand the rationale behind this distinction in behavior. Is there a specific technical or design decision underlying this constraint?

Your insights into this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Actually I read a Jira issue related to this. They were internally doing a column name matching to determine feature columns and output columns and how they need to be fed into the pipeline. I can't link to the issue as I can't search for it.

Comment: Thank you for your input! If anyone happens to find a Jira issue related to this, please share it with us – we would greatly appreciate it.